# Tangential component of a vector given the rotation of a reference unit normal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, rotations

Let $f$ denote a contact force, and $\hat{n}$ the unit normal of a surface at the point where the force is applied. The contact force can be split into tangential and normal components as follows:
$$ f = f_{||} + f_{\perp}. $$

I am looking for a matrix $A$ which gives the tangential component $f_{||}$ in the form of $f_{||} = Af$. For example, for $f = [3,4,5]$ and $\hat{n} = [0,0,1]$, the solution is
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
which would give the tangential component $f_{||} = Af = [3,4,0]$.

My question is: without rotating $f$, but given the rotation matrix that rotates the unit vector [0,0,1] into the surface normal $\hat{n}$, how can I get $A$?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is given $\hat n$ to find a matrix that "kills" $\hat n$, so you need $A\hat n=0$. We can do this by considering a change of basis $\{\hat x,\hat y,\hat z\}$ to $\{\hat x,\hat y,\hat n\}$, then multiplying by $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ to eliminate $\hat n$, then changing back to the original basis. The whole process is represented by the matrix
$$P\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}$$
where $$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&n_1\\0&1&n_2\\0&0&n_3\end{bmatrix}.$$

Furthermore it also has to preserve the tangential component, so you need $A\hat t=\hat t$ where $\hat t$ is the unit vector in the tangential direction. To do this is easy: just multiply the matrix above by a constant to make sure it works. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Let's try your approach for $f = [3, 4, 5]$ and $n = [\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, 0, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}]$. Then, it follows that
$$
A = P S P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 &  0 \\
0 & 0 &  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The result of $An$ is $[0, 0, 0]$, so it successfully "kills" $n$. However, $Af$ results in $[-2, 4, 0]$, which is not the result I am looking for. The result I am looking for can be given, alternatively, by $f_{||} = f - (n ⋅ f)n$, that is $f_{||} = [-1, 4, 1]$. What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: @HenriqueFerrolho The matrix $A$ does not immediately satisfy your requirements (see the last paragraph, where I did not complete the details). The equation $f=(n\cdot f)n+f_\parallel$ implies that $Af=A(n\cdot f)n+Af_\parallel=Af_\parallel$, so we need also to ensure that $Af_\parallel=f_\parallel$, which is what I explained in the last paragraph. (Actually, though, I'm coming to realise that it might not be as easy as constant multiplication to make sure that this is the case, so perhaps my answer is not quite complete. I'll have to think about this a bit further.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I tried to understand your last paragraph but I could not find a way to ensure $Af_\parallel = f_\parallel$.